# msxml:script c# xml fragment with XslCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, xslt, xslcompiledtransform, xpathnodeiterator

Hi I have the following style sheet

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="objGen">
  <xsl:value-of select="cuser:selListNodes('C:\Sitiosweb\Test\xsl\solimporta14.xml')" />
</xsl:variable> 
<xsl:if test="cuser:getNodesLength($objGen)!='0'">
  <xsl:for-each select="$objGen">
    <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending" select="substring(EL01,4,4)" /><xsl:value-of select="user:IncCount()" />
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="EL01" />
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="EL02" />
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="EL03" />
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="EL04" />
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="EL05" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

with the following script in c #

```
<msxml:script language="C#" implements-prefix="cuser">
<msxml:using namespace="System.IO" />

public bool CheckFileExist(string strPath){
  return File.Exists(strPath);
}

public int getNodesLength(XPathNodeIterator objNodes){
   if(objNodes.Count > 0){ return(objNodes.Count); }else{ return(0); }
}

public XPathNodeIterator selListNodes(string nsetCtxt){
    XPathNavigator nav;
    XPathNodeIterator iterator;
    XPathDocument objGenXml = new XPathDocument(nsetCtxt);
    nav = objGenXml.CreateNavigator();
    XPathExpression xPathExpression = nav.Compile("//Listing/Elem");
    iterator = nav.Select(xPathExpression);
    return( iterator );
}
```

the xml value is:

```
<Listing><Elem><EL01><![CDATA[SI-0001-14]]></EL01><EL04><![CDATA[35]]></EL04><EL02><![CDATA[351]]></EL02><EL03><![CDATA[1]]></EL03><EL04><![CDATA[35]]></EL04><EL05><![CDATA[21586]]></EL05><EL06><![CDATA[DALB, INC.]]></EL06><EL07><![CDATA[20140102]]></EL07><EL08><![CDATA[085225]]></EL08><EL09><![CDATA[]]></EL09><EL10><![CDATA[]]></EL10><EL11><![CDATA[]]></EL11><EL12><![CDATA[]]></EL12><EL13><![CDATA[]]></EL13><EL14><![CDATA[]]></EL14><EL15><![CDATA[]]></EL15></Elem><Elem><EL01><![CDATA[SI-0002-14]]></EL01><EL04><![CDATA[35]]></EL04><EL02><![CDATA[1228]]></EL02><EL03><![CDATA[1]]></EL03><EL04><![CDATA[35]]></EL04><EL05><![CDATA[22657]]></EL05><EL06><![CDATA[THE COCA COLA COMPANY]]></EL06><EL07><![CDATA[20140103]]></EL07><EL08><![CDATA[160102]]></EL08><EL09><![CDATA[]]></EL09><EL10><![CDATA[]]></EL10><EL11><![CDATA[]]></EL11><EL12><![CDATA[]]></EL12><EL13><![CDATA[]]></EL13><EL14><![CDATA[]]></EL14><EL15><![CDATA[]]></EL15></Elem></Listing>
```

but when execute the transformation this return error:

```
To use a result tree fragment in a path expression, first convert it to a set of nodes using msxsl: node-set ().
```

my question is there any restriction for XML trees with XslCompiledTransform class? or do I have an error when using the XPathNodeIterator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the XSLT `document` function to load and parse an XML document, there is no need to use C#.
As for the error, if you really think you need to use C#, then define the variable as `<xsl:variable name="objGen" select="cuser:selListNodes(...)"/>`. And to check the count you can simply use the XPath `count($objGen)`.

Comment: Indeed when I use the form:

`<xsl:variable name="objGen">
   <xsl:value-of select="cuser:selListNodes('C:\Sitiosweb\Test\xsl\solimporta14.xml')" />
</ xsl: variable>`

No load data, if use `<xsl:variable name="objGen" select="cuser:selListNodes(...)"/>` then get the data.

I'm using C # function, because depending on other varibles are loading different files to display different data depending on what the user chooses.

Thanks for your answer I clarify this as I can make this work.